# Definition of regular functions on a projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to read *Algebraic Geometry : a First Course* by Joe Harris. In Lecture 2, p. 20, he defines a regular function on an open set $U$ of quasi-projective variety $X$ as a function such that if $U_i$ is the standard open cover of $\mathbb{P}^n$ by open sets isomorphic to affine $n$-space (although I don't think isomorphism has been defined at this moment of the book), the restrictions of $f$ to $U \cap U_i$ is regular. Then he says that it should be noted that this definition is independent of the choice of cover by a lemma which states that the ring of regular functions on a distinguished open subset $U_f$ is the $A(X)[1/f]$, where $A(X)$ denotes the ring of regular functions on $X$.

I have two questions:

1. Why does he define things on an open subset of a quasi-projective variety? Isn't an open subset of a quasi-projective variety a quasi-projective variety itself?
2. How is the fact he mentions about independence of cover proved? I can't see the link with the lemma (and have the impression I can prove it without using it, which is probably false). Moreover, what does he mean when he says that one can choose another cover, does it have to be any open cover or a cover by open subsets isomorphic to affine space?

Comment: He does *not* define regular functions on quasi-projective varieties on page 18: he defines regular functions on affine varieties $X\subset \mathbb A^n$. Anyway,  I strongly advise you not to try to study basic algebraic geometry from that book.

Comment: By the way,  you are right: an open subset of a quasi-projective variety is quasi-projective.

Comment: Yes, indeed, what I meant is p. 20. Why do you advise not to study basic algebraic geometry from this book? I've read that it has great examples, although when it comes to theory, it's a bit hard to follow, which is exactly what I'm experiencing. Is that the reason?

Comment: Yes, exactly ${}{}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try Shafarevich, then.

Comment: @Georges, which book will you personally prefer?